# Transferring files from OS X to an Ubuntu Server seems to not copy all the data

Tags: files, ftp, macosx, transfer

I have a problem (or at least I think I have a problem) that I am facing for a while an have found no solution so far - to be honest, I am not sure if it is a "real" problem at all, but I am unsure about that and found nowhere else an answer. That is why I am desperately hoping for some insight from here.

The situation is the following:

I have an OS X work machine (a Mac Book Air to be precise) and an Ubuntu 12.04 file server.

Now all I wanted to do is to back up (a lot) of data from the OS X machine to the server. However, that does not seem to work, as it seems never all the data is transferred - no luck whatever I try.

To not make it overly complicated, let's just concentrate on my music library in 
/Users/me/Music/iTunes.

The recent try I did was to use ftp (ncftp on the client, vsftpd on ubuntu)
After the ftp put -R iTunes I have:

on OS X: Total Size 43,09 GB 10289 Items
on Ubuntu : Total Size 37,58 GB 9293 Items

Why is that so? This data cannot be correct, right? Or am I missing something?

I have tried:

- smb (drag and drop the folders)
- scp
- rsync

There are always a few GB(!) missing and a whole lot of files (the number varies, however).
In my desperation, I even tried to use git...but alas, in the case of my Music library it 
bails out early as it cannot handle that much data.

Has someone any idea why I seemingly are not able to make a good backup of my files over the network? Am I doing someting wrong? I understand that sizes may differ from file system to filesystem, but they wont in the GB range, will they?

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size and number may not matter. There are blank files (zero length) or directories, preview images (thumbnail), and other anomalies. Also files sizes will change radically on a different file system.

---

You need to retry, with a **smaller sample**.  Try one artist, or one album / collection.  Then try to identify what *actually useful* data files were **not** copied.

*Report back on your findings, adding details to the question.*

Comment: Allright, I will do so. For now I'm facing another problem on my mac (zipped the Music folder, transferred it, deleted it and now my OSX HD reports 40 gig being missing... :()

Comment: The only problem I am facing with your answer is that I can believe that being in the ... say kb/mb even 1GB size - but i cannot believe that ~5,5 GB "waste" data is used on osx drives vs linux drives..